# How can I use round dots in my animated line in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: animation, path, html5-canvas, rounding

I am using line creation on HTML5 canvas to create two animated dashed paths, one after the other. I simply want to change the dashes to rounded dots.

I've seen setting context lineCap ='round', etc but it doesn't work

```js
       

        var canvas;
        var ctx;

        var pathColor="black";

        function Vector(x, y)
  {
   this.X = x;
   this.Y = y;
  }
  var m1, c1;

        var pCount1=0;
        var pCount2=0;

  var pathInt = null;

  var points1 = [new Vector(1400, 1500),new Vector(1365, 1495),new Vector(1330, 1490),new Vector(1295, 1485),new Vector(1260, 1480)];
  var points2 = [new Vector(1280, 480),new Vector(1195, 470),new Vector(1110, 460),new Vector(1080, 450),new Vector(1000, 240),new Vector(1300, 140),new Vector(1580, 140),new Vector(1590, 180),];

        function getClr() {
            if(pathColor=="lightgrey") {
                pathColor="black";
            }
            else {
                pathColor="lightgrey";
            }
        }       

  window.onload = function()
  {
   m1 = document.querySelector("#b");
   c1 = m1.getContext("2d");  

            pathInt = setInterval(function(){ pathTo(); }, 250);   
  };

        function pathTo()
   {    

                if(pCount1 <= points1.length  && points1.length!=0)
                {
                 c1.strokeStyle = pathColor;
                 c1.lineWidth = 15;
                 c1.setLineDash([25, 10]);

                 c1.beginPath();
                 c1.moveTo(points1[0].X, points1[0].Y);

                 for(var i = 0; i < pCount1; i++)
                 {
                  c1.lineTo(points1[i].X, points1[i].Y);
                 }

                    pCount1++;
                    c1.stroke();
                }
                else if(pCount2 <= points2.length && points2.length!=0)
                {

                 c1.strokeStyle = pathColor;
                 c1.lineWidth = 15;
                 c1.setLineDash([25, 10]);

                 c1.beginPath();
                 c1.moveTo(points2[0].X, points2[0].Y);

                 for(var i = 1; i < pCount2; i++)
                 {
                  c1.lineTo(points2[i].X, points2[i].Y);
                 }

                    pCount2++;
                    c1.stroke();

                    pCount2++;

                }
                else {
                    clearInterval(pathInt);

                    setTimeout(function(){ redoPath(); }, 5000);  
                }
   
   }

            function redoPath() {
                pCount1=0;
                pCount2=0;
                //c1.clearRect(0, 0, m1.width, m1.height);

                getClr();

                pathInt = setInterval(function(){ pathTo(); }, 250); 
            }
```

```html
<canvas id="b" width="1746" height="1746" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:50px;z-index:100;">  
</canvas>
```

I know this must be possible, ..but not sure which properties I need to change. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try something like `c1.setLineDash([1, 30]); c1.lineCap = "round";`. And by the way: this is not svg is html5-canvas

Comment: hmm that's what I tried before but now it works. Something is obviously different but thx!